# How to get actually value of item in for loop over a 1D Numpy float array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to use a for loop to add sum of squares for random numbers in a numpy float array, however I am unable to get a final sum and get an array instead. It seems like the type of item I get from the loop for the float array is a 1d array item instead of the actual value.

The sum from the loop works when I create a random numpy array of integers. This was run in a jupyter notebook. I want the original sum to look like sum2. Thanks!

```
test = np.random.randn(1,5000000)
sum = float(0)
test2 = np.random.randint(1,11,5000000)
sum2 = float(0)

test
for x in test:
  sum = sum + (x * x)
print(sum)
```

**Output**: [0.90913299 1.41379817 0.62241195 ... 6.05354146 0.37052478 0.60846973]

```
test2
for x in test2:
  sum2 = sum2 + (x * x)
print(sum2)
```

**Output**: 192468061.0

Comment: Why are you using loops for this? It defeats the purpose of using Numpy. Regardless, if you [read the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) you will see that `randn()` gives yo a different shape and its use is discouraged in favor of `standard_normal`.

Comment: Thanks for the intuition. I need to compare the manual for loop iteration to the better approach using Numpy to do this. @MarkMeyer

Comment: You can do something like `np.sum(test ** 2)` and it will be orders of magnitude faster than a python loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is a 2d array:

```
In [16]: test = np.random.randn(1,10)
In [17]: test.shape
Out[17]: (1, 10)
In [18]: test
Out[18]: 
array([[-0.24668889,  1.63924792,  0.43071196, -0.48847854,  1.68450449,
        -0.32010578, -0.62775688, -1.15134612,  2.42900228,  1.16697956]])
```

This iteration operates on the first dimension, which is size 1:

```
In [20]: for x in test:
    ...:     print(x)

[-0.24668889  1.63924792  0.43071196 -0.48847854  1.68450449 -0.32010578
 -0.62775688 -1.15134612  2.42900228  1.16697956]
```

In your code the `for` just feeds one row at at time to your sum.

`test2` is a 1d array:

```
In [21]: test2 = np.random.randint(1,11,10)
In [22]: test2.shape
Out[22]: (10,)
In [23]: test2
Out[23]: array([ 3,  8,  3,  1,  1,  3, 10,  6,  6, 10])
In [24]: for x in test2:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...: 
3
8
3
1
1
3
10
6
6
10
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if you check the size of `test` and `test2` using `len(test)` and `len(test2)`, you will notice the difference.

To get a similar result as `sum2`, you could run:

```py
sum = 0  
for x in test[0]:
    sum += x*x
```